# Make app free for users who already purchased previous versions

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Suppose I upload my app (version 1.0) to App store with a price of 1.99 USD. Later I'll upload a version(1.1) with some upgradations but again with a same price tag(1.99 USD). I want my previous users(who purchased version 1.0) to download the version 1.1 for free.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a normal App Store update sounds like. Any users who have already downloaded your app can download the update for free any other users will have to pay your current price for your app if they wish to purchase it.

Comment: Does Apple takes care of this issue?

Comment: @John Apple does exactly what I mentioned above. Users who already have purchased/downloaded your app will be able to download any updates for free. Users who have not purchased/downloaded your app ever will have to pay the current price you set to get your app. Updates don't really affect price. Price and updates are pretty separate. Current users get updates for free. Other users just have to download/purchase your app. Your old version will no longer be available either.

Comment: Thanks, now take another case. App version 1.0 had a price of 1.99 USD, now version 1.1 will have a price tag of 2.99 USD. Now what's gonna happen to the user who already paid for version 1.0 and wants to upgrade to version 1.1?

Comment: @John ALL App Store updates are free. You can't charge for updates to your app. So existing customers will still be able to get the update no charge and such. If you change your price tag new users will still have to pay that updated price. The only way to require old users to pay extra is through In-App Purchases which do have limitations. But all updates downloaded through the App Store currently are free.

Comment: So in that case that users who has paid for 1.0 and wants to upgrade to 1.1 will be able to do so free of charge.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @John No problem! Glad to help!! Thanks for accepting the answer. :)